# .NET Maui cannot deploy to older IOS versions

Tags: ios, xcode, maui

My setup is:

- macOS Monterey (can’t upgrade due to h/w limitations)
- Visual Studio for Mac 2022
- Xcode version is 14.2
- Xamarin IOS, downloaded to 16.2 as recommended [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Xamarin-16406-requires-XCode-143-bit/10353330)
- Application .NET 7 MAUI application

Requirement is for the application to target an older version of IOS, such as 14.5 so that I can run and debug the application on the simulator.

Xcode has IOS 14.5 downloaded and runs/simulates applications targeting this version with no problems.

If I select IOS 14.5 emulator as the run target and click run, application generates following error messages:

```
/Projects/Test8/Test8/ILLINK: Error MT0180: This version of Microsoft.iOS requires the iOS 16.4 SDK (shipped with Xcode 14.3). Either upgrade Xcode to get the required header files or set the managed linker behaviour to Link Framework SDKs Only in your project's iOS Build Options > Linker Behavior (to try to avoid the new APIs). (MT0180) (Test8)
```

When I try to change the target IOS versions from default 16.1 to 14.5 on project properties, all simulators disappear. Lowest supported IOS version is set to 11.0.

Furthermore, when I change target IOS to 14.5, close properties window and come back to properties I find that target field blank.

A screen capture of the issue can be seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyH-8g2X5do)

Comment: 1) *"This version of Microsoft.MacCatalyst..."* - In project properties, UNCHECK MacCatylst target. 2) Might need to manually edit `.csproj` to get desired iOS version. Sounds like VS Mac has some issue setting via project properties.

Comment: Thank you, error message is updated. Not trying to target Catalyst otherwise. I keep editing .csproj however whenever I set it to anything other than IOS 16.1 I stop getting targets for IOS completely (on the top selector, as seen in the video)

Comment: Unfortunately, must be a bug in VS Mac + Maui when targeting older iOS. Don’t know why. Is that XCode the highest one you can run on that MacOS? If so, file an issue against VS Mac.